# Large data from Javascript to servlet

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have very large data like say a 100 lines text file in my `<div>` tag,

So I want to passtint to my `java` servlet and I've tried the following methods by getting the `<div>` value in `javascript`

**Method 1:**

```
var script = ace.edit("AceEditor"); //Getting the editor text value
var myDivText = script.getValue();
```

Function to add hidden and submit the form

```
function addHidden(UploadFile, key, value) {
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = key;
input.value = value;
UploadFile.appendChild(input);
}
```

Access the function

```
var UploadFile = document.forms['RunMy'];
addHidden(UploadFile, 'UserMyScript', myDivText);
document.RunMy.submit();
```

**Method 2:**

Get Editor text,

```
var script = ace.edit("AceEditor");
var myDivText = script.getValue();

window.open('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8085/FirstServlet/my?mytxt=' + myDivText);
```

But, I've faced problems with both the methods as the data is being passed through the `URL` and data being very large here, the `URL` size is limited.

So, is there any method to pass large text from `javascript` to `servlet`?

Base on answer below, I've edited stuff like this

```
$("#execute1").click(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: '/YourServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: $('#AceEditor'.val()) },
});
});
```

But when I click the `execute1` button, the browser console shows

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function MYJsp:144
(anonymous function) MYJsp:144
x.event.dispatch jquery.js:5095
v.handle
```

Comment: Nope, I am not using `springMVC`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont you try with jquery ajax post,

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/YourServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { value: $('#AceEditor'.val()) },
    success: function(result) {
        alert('the request was successfully sent to the server');
    }
});
```

And in your servlet get the values of the `string` using `getParameter()`

see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to know more about jquery ajax post

Hope this helps !!

Comment: So on my servlet side I must use `request.getParameter(AceEditor)` right?

Comment: no , you are passing the values as `value` right . then you should `request.getParameter("value")`

Comment: have you imported `jquery` library

Comment: Yes I did `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Might be some error on the syntax , go through it carefully or post your complete java script code